# Angular Firebase - DocumentReference.set() error

Tags: angular, firebase

I followed a tutorial with regards to building a authentication system for the purpose of learning. I understand the basic behavior and have made changes to fit my needs, however I am running into an error below.

```
FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field admin)
```

I am trying to navigate through the Firebase documentation to find a specific instructions on how to declare custom fields but I cannot find what I am looking for. I am pretty sure it has to deal with;

```
    SetUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified:user.emailVerified,
      admin: user.admin
    }
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    })
  }
```

I would really like some help on trying to understand how to properly setup custom data, and I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

auth.service

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "../../models/user/user";
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // Save logged in user data

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,   
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
    public router: Router,  
    public ngZone: NgZone 
  ) {    
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })
  }

  SignIn(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['account']);
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
  }

  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  AuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
       this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['account']);
        })
      this.SetUserData(result.user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }

  SetUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified:user.emailVerified,
      admin: user.admin
    }
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    })
  }

  SignOut() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    })
  }

}
```

user

```
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  displayName: string;
  photoURL: string;
  emailVerified: boolean;
  admin: boolean;
}
```

Console output

```
 User 
    Q {G: Array(0), m: "AIzaSyCMcvKFB-xcIpuc_y23924dDZgYJ1aBfCw", o: "
    G: []
    I: true
    N: [ƒ]
    O: []
    Rb: Q {G: Array(0), m: "AIzaSyCMcvKFB-xcIpuc_y23924dDZgYJ1aBfCw", o: "
    V: ƒ ()
    Va: null
    W: bm {m: false, settings: Rk, app: FirebaseAppImpl, b: Jh, N: Array(0), …}
    X: bm {m: false, settings: Rk, app: FirebaseAppImpl, b: Jh, N: Array(0), …}
xcIpuc_y23924dDZgYJ1aBfCw", m: "[DEFAULT]", h: Array(2), f: true, …}
    b: Jh {b: "AIzaSyCMcvKFB-xcIpuc_y23924dDZgYJ1aBfCw", i: "https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token", l: Ce, f: {…}, g: "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/", …}
    ba: Pl {a: "AIzaSyCMcvKFB-xcIpuc_y23924dDZgYJ1aBfCw:[DEFAULT]", b: Kj}

    emailVerified: true
    h: Yk {f: Jh, a: "AEu4IL30a2_ONvQNEZ6vrNX4Ps-F_so4U8lgoJ2Dk3gZcu__35…NsyUKyuirXYpjGTnw0VggX4Gk9CkP3CUVr0woBmgyu3-oEOsI", b: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjkwYmVmMzI2MmVkMzI0Mz…Q5HOt8Pyffn-K3smoXuy31tOcWwubVGgGobX1Bs3NhU8xiJAg", c: 1552345513374}
    i: null
    isAnonymous: false
    ja: undefined
    ka: null
    l: lc {src: Q, a: {…}, b: 3}
    m: "AIzaSyCMcvKFB-xcIpuc_y23924dDZgYJ1aBfCw"
    metadata: cl {a: "1551803509525", b: "1552341792606", lastSignInTime: "Mon, 11 Mar 2019 22:03:12 GMT", creationTime: "Tue, 05 Mar 2019 16:31:49 GMT"}
    o: "[DEFAULT]"
    phoneNumber: null
    photoURL: "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-br2Ryja4cjk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAPk/DW5PcRH3R8I/photo.jpg"
    providerData: [el]
    qa: false
    ra: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjkwYmVmMzI2MmVkMzI0MzZkNzhlMjdjYWJhYzg3YmIwZWUxZGYwYzIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.VUTov7Mxgbu48lBeW62B_bmkwk92ZaJBOAk60zw5DsEv184WriTNDSM-E3qFbTpsrObuZTmnKLjskzuBZ_lEA1o9hCX7AYPKUTORRaTV_6facxfKqT8c2FGkAgVZtdRB6sOa5pIMRxUVQiMSG42VTqVtelp5uWcBwVLTGeisCfOG6yQDICjSEq1Bz2mIivjFbVRTMuN7K8_2HKe_ZvnbtSOYhWKVWPk4trqP2_6TI8GLpzyNEHvbeUrN22Sqk_1XpexP07MK8o4Xgi_Wu2-_DmKFtR5yCGazxzrOAQ5HOt8Pyffn-K3smoXuy31tOcWwubVGgGobX1Bs3NhU8xiJAg"
    refreshToken: "AEu4IL30a2_ONvQNEZ6vrNX4Ps-F_so4U8lgoJ2Dk3gZcu__35q5nf5fiQ6socOlY0w1BuGRGYBcj9llVFuONti8owFovgwosVMopaC57Vn5Q0hPsq7b1i2dDFg3YYxOtVopNp1owjs4H6QAgG_pkozYyKcL4cNx3dWTH7ZvEPT-upyWe0IhkcpxxmkRTZaoX4_Iy8GA-Z4vebW0-CAfbFcUjziEkZN1sq3hvN1HHCaA5uvrKoCdGYC3NhUtqteRh77Te0khvZ_ZemWLqkcQjEwB7lBoZnlw3nYskQNOWh8OWm8xvdseALjlkpMXeUYDTUO7S9NsyUKyuirXYpjGTnw0VggX4Gk9CkP3CUVr0woBmgyu3-oEOsI"
    sa: ƒ (a)
    ta: ƒ (a)

    uid: "tUieIMXVuhhO0Q0E2gMmii4sJA03"
    w: Vk {h: ƒ, i: ƒ, g: ƒ, c: 30000, f: 960000, …}
    _lat: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjkwYmVmMzI2MmVkMzI0MzZkNzhlMjdjYWJhYzg3YmIwZWUxZGYwYzIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.VUTov7Mxgbu48lBeW62B_bmkwk92ZaJBOAk60zw5DsEv184WriTNDSM-E3qFbTpsrObuZTmnKLjskzuBZ_lEA1o9hCX7AYPKUTORRaTV_6facxfKqT8c2FGkAgVZtdRB6sOa5pIMRxUVQiMSG42VTqVtelp5uWcBwVLTGeisCfOG6yQDICjSEq1Bz2mIivjFbVRTMuN7K8_2HKe_ZvnbtSOYhWKVWPk4trqP2_6TI8GLpzyNEHvbeUrN22Sqk_1XpexP07MK8o4Xgi_Wu2-_DmKFtR5yCGazxzrOAQ5HOt8Pyffn-K3smoXuy31tOcWwubVGgGobX1Bs3NhU8xiJAg"
    __proto__: F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Afternoon! Check out your SetUserData() method. It seems that the user object you're trying to persist doesn't have a value on the admin property. Try `console.log('User', result.user);` before `this.SetUserData(result.user);` And please post the console log. Have Fun.